# Ember.js binding array element to view

Tags: ember.js

I have the following code in a ember.js template. userController is an ArrayController, with multipe "users" within.

```
{{#each CollaborativeEditor.userController}}
    {{#view CollaborativeEditor.OnlineUserView userBinding="this"}}
        <div class="avatar">
            <div class="avatar_name">{{name}}</div>
            <div class="avatar_status">{{status}}</div>
        </div>
        <div id="dropdown-1">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" {{action startChat target="onlineUser"}}>Talk to </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    {{/view}}
{{/each}}
```

This is the code of the respective view:

```
CollaborativeEditor.OnlineUserView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    startChat : function() {
        console.log(this.get('user'));
    }       
});
```

Although, the name and status is set correctly for each user, the startChat action attached to the link always prints the first user of the array to the console.
What is wrong with the binding ?

Comment: interresting, are you able to put this in a jsfiddle please ? http://jsfiddle.net/6p6XJ/

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot for your request, to put it in a jsfiddle !

While I was trying to reproduce the error there, I realized the problem, and it has nothing to do with ember.

The div with id="dropdown-1" was called from another link and it was always the same id, therefore always the same action with its user-binding.

Now I've bound the Id to the user-object and it works perfectly.

Comment: oh yes, good catch, I did'nt realize it reading the template. Anyway +1 for you :)